# Is there any way of using dataframe created in different python script on another script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-import

I know that functions can be imported from one script to another but is there anyway of doing same with DataFrame or other variables.

Comment: probably not the most effienct solution, but you can export it to csv : `df.to_csv('Path') `and load it back in another file with `pd.read_csv('Path')`

Comment: How about pickling the dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

Comment: What is your goal: To save loading time, to transfer a selection from a bigger dataset (i.e. to preserve the selection criteria/results), to transfer the results of new computations? There might be different solutions, depending.

Comment: I have many scripts and each of them are creating one final dataframe, now I want to use all of these final dataframes in one other script, so one way can be of I create all these dataframes at one place only then perform the operation there only but the scripts are large in number so I don't want to make all of them in one script only.

Comment: The common way is to import the other scripts, and use the functions from those scripts to create the dataframes.

Comment: have you tried `from script_name.py import df_name`? either that or storing as a file, whether pickling, csv, or otherwise

Comment: @Zulfiqaar I am sorry, I am a beginner this is what I was searching for but could not get. Yes this worked.

Comment: Storing your df would be one option. But I'd suggest to use pickle or hdf to store it, rather than csv. In case you need csv for any reason, you should make sure to store the types of the columns, so you can restore them. Otherwise pandas will guess the types itself which often results in generously chosen numeric types. Another suggestion would be to use spyder. In case you don't mind running the scripts from an ide, you can just run one script and start the next script in the same interpreter, without having to reload anything.

Comment: @Zulfiqaar It was working fine yesterday but today it is throwing an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abc.py'; 'abc' is not a package" on the code line "from abc.py import df_abc" and I have no idea why it was working fine yesterday but have stopped now.